# Reversing results for current page (django paginator generic view)

Tags: django, django-pagination

I'm using the standard django paginator in my generic view like this:

```
def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(ArchivePagedView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs) 
        article_list = Article.published
        #=====================================
        paginator = Paginator(article_list, self.paginate_by)
        page = self.request.GET.get('page')

        try:
            article_list = paginator.page(page)
        except PageNotAnInteger:
            article_list = paginator.page(1)
        except EmptyPage:
            article_list = paginator.page(paginator.num_pages)


        if 'reverse' in self.request.GET:
            article_list = article_list.reverse() #This doesn't work!
        else:
            article_list = article_list.all()

        context['article_list'] = article_list

        return context
```

As you can see I want to override `article_list` with the same list, but in reversed direction, if `reverse` is in the URL in behind the question mark. That information I get by `'reverse' in self.request.GET`.
But I get an error: `AttributeError: 'Page' object has no attribute 'reverse'`. How do I reverse this? (I don't want to have duplicated code in my template.)

Before I fixed this by making an extra `context` variable (`context['reverse']`) which says whether the list should be reversed or not, and then I used duplicated code like this:

```
{% if reverse %}
 {% for article in article_list reversed %}
  ... some code
 {% endfor %}
{% else %}
 {% for article in article_list %}
  ... the same code
 {% endfor %}
{% endif %}
```

I wonder if there was no better solution.

Comment: @knbk this is exactly what I want. I don't want to reverse before paginating.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
article_list.object_list = list(reversed(article_list.object_list))
```

Comment: I tried this in `get_context_data`: `if 'reverse' in self.request.GET:
   article_list.object_list = reversed(article_list.object_list)

  context['article_list'] = article_list`. I got an error: `object of type 'reversed' has no len()`

Comment: Thank you for the hint, it should be `article_list.object_list.reverse()` instead of using `reversed`.

Comment: `queryset.reverse()` together with slicing as used by the paginator can change the items in the queryset. To keep the same results but reverse them, you need to use `reversed()` and convert it to a list, so: `list(reversed(article_list.object_list))`.

Comment: @L_S Unfortunately not :( It reverses everything, not only the current page. That means, the first item is now the last on the last page, not the last on the first page.